# Returning an array allocated with malloc and not using the return

Tags: c, malloc, computer-science

I am writing a function which returns an array. In this function I want to do some calculations to give me an integer, which is the size of the array I want to allocate memory to. In the function I therefore use malloc to allocate an array with the specific size and I return this array called returnArray.

However, what happens if I call the function without using the return? Will the allocated memory still be allocated? Is this a very bad problem? I suspect memory leak, but I'm not entirely sure.

```
char * findValueAndCreateArray() {
int value = 0;

while(something, something..) {
value++;
}

char * returnArray = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * value);

return returnArray;

}

findValueAndCreateArray;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should show your code to make the question more clear. If your function returns the address of the allocated memory and you don't use and later `free` it, you will create a memory leak. This is not much different from calling `malloc(some_size)` and ignoring its return value.

Comment: @Bodo I now added the code. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will do a memory leak. When you return something from a function in C, you just copy a value. So when you are doing a `malloc()`, you catch the adress of your allocated memory but this space will be allocated until the end of your program or a `free(returnArray);`

And also, you should use a `size_t` variable when you are allocating space with `malloc`.